# How to Connect to Bluetooth (Adapter) under Artix (Arch) OpenRC

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, openrc, artix-linux

I have a Bluetooth USB adapter that I plug into my desktop PC to help me connect to Bluetooth stuff. It works perfectly under Windows 10. Except that I really can't get it to work with Artix OpenRC dual-boot, despite having installed all of the relevant packages and having watched and read many tutorials. (My headphones are Sony's `LE_WH-1000XM3`)

The closest I could get to something working was following [this Gentoo OpenRC tutorial](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bluetooth), but, at the very end, when trying `connect device_mac_address` all I get is a vague error message — yes, I have done `rfkill unblock bluetooth` —:

```
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

And, if I try to pair it again, I get `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists`. Quite frankly, I find `bluetoothctl`'s error messages quite terse and cryptic.

---

I have many packages installed, including:

```
alsa-utils
blueberry
blueman
bluez
bluez-tools
bluez-utils
bluetooth
bluetooth-openrc
pavucontrol
pulseaudio-alsa
pulseaudio-bluetooth
pulseaudio-ctl
```

So far, I have been using my headphones through cable, but even then I can't say the behavior has been very consistent. Sometimes I have to open `pavucontrol` and hack around to see if a specific configuration manages to enable to headphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, if I open Blueberry and Pavucontrol *at the same time*, everything works. And the sound quality is even better than I thought.

I've been going through this setup for some days already and it hasn't failed me yet.

Additionally, if I close any of the programs I mentioned, after about 30s, the Bluetooth connection is terminated, i.e., I have to keep both open. I guess most desktop environments kind of do this, by keeping them in the background.